# how to get total number of pages using pdftk?

Tags: php, pdftk

i am using pdftk to get total page number of a pdf file in php.
I am using the code.
 my pdftk.exe file is in

> assets/pdftk folder
>   and my pdf file is in 
>   Files folder

```
$command = '../assets/pdftk/pdftk.exe ';
$command.="../Files/" . $fileNames;
$command.="dump_data | grep NumberOfPages";
exec($command);
```

i need to get number of pages in a string.how to do this.thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
$pageCount = intval('pdftk path/to/pdf.pdf dump_data | grep "NumberOfPages" | cut -d":" -f2');
```